# XAML: transform position on panel without transforming the element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to position elements on a `Canvas` (in my case it's several graphical and text elements) and **transform the position** of these elements by a `Transform`, but **not** transform the **elements themselves**. The `Transform` needs to be changed dynamically, like for resizing or changing the rotation angle. I do not want to touch the elements but only the transform that I am binding to.

What I have now:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="IDEAUserInterfaces.StationaryUI.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <TranslateTransform x:Key="translate" X="10" Y="10"/>
        <ScaleTransform x:Key="scale" ScaleX="0.8" ScaleY="1.3"/>
        <RotateTransform x:Key="rotate" Angle="30"/>
        <TransformGroup x:Key="group">
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="translate"/>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="scale"/>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="rotate"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
            <Canvas Name="elementCanvas" Canvas.Top="15" Canvas.Left="20">
                <Path Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="1">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Center="0,0" Transform="{Binding StaticResource group}"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
                <TextBlock Text="Text" Canvas.Left="10" FontSize="10"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Obviously the position of *elementCanvas* sets the position of the contained graphics and text. Setting `Transform` on the `EllipseGeometry` transforms the whole geometry. I found no way to tranform a `Point` in XAML, for example the `Center`-property of EllipseGeomtry. Still this would not change the position of the `TextBlock`.

Transforming `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` would be enough, I think, but how could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with a generic solution, that lets me position elements on Canvases with Transforms:

MultiBinding.

I created two Multibinding classes that take the Transform and the coordinates (for translation, scaling and shearing it would take only one coordinate, but for rotations it needs both X and Y) and returns the coordinate transformed by the Transform. So I calculate the two coordinates in two Multibindings.

For Points I have a third Multibinding converter that returns transformed Points.

It takes some lines in XAML, but there is no specific code in codebehind, and scaling of the Canvas works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to `Transform` the UI elements, then don't use any kind of `Transform` objects on them. If you data bind the positions of your elements on the `Canvas`, then you can just update the relevant properties of the relevant elements and they will move accordingly:

```
<Style x:Key="ElementStyle">
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}" />
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}" />
</Style>

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourElements}"
    ItemsContainerStyle="{StaticResource ElementStyle}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Then to update their positions, you could just do this:

```
element.Left = newPosition.X;
element.Top = newPosition.Y;
```

To be clear, you'd have to declare a `Left` and a `Top` proeprty in your data class that represents your UI elements. You can read the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for more information about Data Binding in general.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to avoid: Go overy every element and change the position by hand. The `Transform` should be the only thing that I need to change... Updated the question to make that more clear.

Comment: *Transforming Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left would be enough, I think, but how could this be done?*... *This* is how it is done.

Comment: And how should I bind a `Transform` to `Canvas.Top`?

Comment: For completeness, the `Transform` can be bound to `Canvas.Top` with a `Multibinding` and a `Converter`. See my own anser.